# Bringing Wiki page up on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to get a wiki page to display on IOS. This is the first assignment in my 8-week course and I am completely lost. I have only worked with Java, Swift is a completely new language and I cant seem to find a starting point. My professor has only showed us how to bring objects into the view controller such as segmented control bars and buttons, but has not showed us how to implement code into program to interact with the objects.

I know this is a long shot, and I have exhausted all other options (even bought an IOS 9 book) but if anyone can provide a starting amount of code for me to see and work with I would be extremely grateful. I am not asking for the whole project, I just need to be able to see an example of some starting code that I can hopefully follow and progress with.

[Project Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeCoW.png) /
[Project Example Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Idl.png)

Comment: The way to interact with your UI elements placed via Interface Builder is to use IB Outlets. IB Outlets can be made by opening up the Assistant Editor (The hamburger in the top right of Xcode) and holding control + drag on the element of choice and dragging it into the code

Comment: This seems like a weird course.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the instructions, it seems like you'll need to have a multi-component [UIPickerView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-uipickerview) (this is a basic tutorial, you can use it to get the delegate methods used to interact with the pickerView, here's a more [in depth tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-YJLHEIpzU)) and definitely will need to use multiple UIViewControllers in order to achieve the desired result. Add BarButton Items to the bottom of the view, and control+drag on those to connect them to additional ViewControllers which can be used to select Plant/Animal Name, and to change the textColor.

On the initial viewContoller, you'll need a WKWebView above your imageView, learn more about their implementation [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/112/the-ultimate-guide-to-wkwebview) (note that this shows a programmatic approach, your wkWebView will likely be connected to your code from Interface Builder using an IBOutlet).

Continue to ask questions as they arise.

Comment: This looks like it is going to very informative. Thank you! I will get back to you if I have anymore questions.